# Set height of UITableViewCell correctly so that UITableviewCell subclass has the correct Bounds

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm using a gradient for my cell background. But If I use

```
gradient.Frame = this.Bounds
```

it uses the default height of the `UITableViewCell`. I tried to use `GetHeightForRow` function as well as `this.TableView.RowHeight = 60` but every time the gradient has the height of the default height of the cell.

Currently I'm using

```
gradient.Frame = new RectangleF (this.Bounds.X, this.Bounds.Y, this.Bounds.Width, 60);
```

but is there a way that `Bounds` has the correct height (as set with `RowHeight` for example)?

The code is for C# but the Objective-C solution would be very similar.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think what you want is something like this..within your table view delegate method have it setup like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ReusableCellID"];

    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gradient.png"];
    UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake:(cell.frame.origin.x,cell.frame.origin.y,cell.frame.size.width,cell.frame.size.height)];
    imgView.image = image;
    [cell.backgroundView addSubview:imgView];

return cell;
```

}

Comment: I'm using storyboard. On the `UITableView` I switched to Layout and I set the `Row Height` from 44 to 60 but nothing has changed.

Comment: Have you created a custom UITableViewCell or are you using a standard one?

Comment: Check the edited answer..I misunderstood the question initially

Comment: It's a custom cell. I don't find `origin` in my case for Xamarin. I tried it with `gradient.Frame = new RectangleF (this.Bounds.X, this.Bounds.Y, this.Frame.Size.Width, this.Frame.Size.Height);` but the height is still the default one. I've to mention that I set the gradient on the custom table cell class instead in `GetCell` (cellForRowAtIndexPath).